# YouCompleteMe gives continiously error in Vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim, shell-script, vim-plugins

I recently started to use ubuntu to learn bash script. I installed `vim-addon-manager` & `YouCompleteMe` for auto-completion in Vim. After that, when I run Vim and try to write something, I get this error continuously. 
[image]

I found no usefull solutio. How can I solve this ?

FYI: I tried to use this command, but it fails to solve this problem.

> git submodule update --init --recursive

Comment: It looks like your vim doesn't have python `vim --version` should list something like `+python3`

Comment: @Steven , it has `+python3` in the list

Comment: Seems you have yet to run through the compilation process on outlined on [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#ubuntu-linux-x64)? This is a great plugin, takes a while time to get it running though.